# If $A>0$ , $\rho (A)$ has algebraic multiplicity $k > 1$ , $x$ is Perron vectors then $x = (A - \rho (A)I)z$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and $A>0$,(all $a_{ij}>0$) and  $\rho (A)$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Suppose

- $\rho (A) = \max \{ \left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda $ is eigenvalue of $A$   $\}$)
- $\rho (A)$ has algebraic multiplicity $k > 1$
- $x$ is the right Perron vectors of $A$,.

Can we say that, there is a nonzero
vector $z$ such that  $x = (A - \rho (A)I)z$?

Comment: Since nullity of $A-\rho(A)I$ equals $1$ (as per Perron-Frobenius theorem), such generalized eigenvector $z$ does exist. What are your doubts?

Comment: For positive matrices the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue [is simple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem#Positive_matrices), so $k>1$ is impossible. Maybe you mean $a_{ij}\ge 0$?

Comment: @Abstraction  Why does nullity of $A-\rho(A)I$ equals 1?

Comment: @H.S I remembered that Perron-Frobenius theorem states that geometric multiplicity of $\rho(A)$ is $1$ (which is exactly what nullity of $A-\rho(A)I$ is). Now that I checked, it *also* states  that algebraic multiplicity of $\rho(A)$ is $1$, so described situation is indeed impossible (as stated by **A.G.**).

Comment: @Abstraction - Thanks, so, if $k=1$ then this question is true.Ok?

Comment: @H.S No, if $k=1$ there is no generalized eigenvector (remember how Jordan form looks like in that case).

Comment: @Abstraction - I dont understand $K=?$ Please more guide.

Comment: @H.S Ok. Question 1: do you remember what Jordan form is? Question 2: do you remember what generalized eigenvector (which is $z$) is and when it exists for given eigenvalue?

Comment: @Abstraction - No, I'm sorry.